# How to find $\operatorname{div} F$ and $\operatorname{curl} F$ of the vector field $F=\hat r=\cos\theta \hat{\imath} + \sin\theta \hat{\jmath}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was given a bunch of divergence and curl questions in class but I am stumped on this one. If anyone can help explain what I should do with it I would appreciate it.

> Calculate $\operatorname{div} F$ and $\operatorname{curl} F$ of the vector field $F=\hat r=\cos\theta \hat{\imath} + \sin\theta \hat{\jmath}$.

I understood div and curl for Cartesian coordinates but I don't know what to do here. Again, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In cartesian coordinates,
$$
\vec{F} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \hat{\imath} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \hat{\jmath}.
$$

You can probably calculate $\operatorname{div} \vec{F}$ and $\operatorname{curl} \vec{F}$ now.

Comment: You can use `\imath` and `\jmath` to get versions of i and j without the dots, which are nice when you want hats on them.

Comment: AAA yes! thank you very much for this little trick.